# Show a command inside a `...` icon in the view/item/context

Tags: treeview, vscode-extensions

The ref: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/tree-view#view-actions

It says `view/item/context` - Location to show actions for the tree item. Inline actions use `"group": "inline"` and rest are secondary actions, which are in `...` menu.

I want to put some command in the `...` menu, but only got it in the context menu dropdown.

Any idea to put it under the `...`?

I find the solution in the github and the vscode official doc. But it always put it into the dropdown menu item.

Comment: I think that passage you quoted about a `...` menu is wrong.  The image in the docs that follows don't show a `...` option for `view/item/context`.  I tried a few things and could not get any `...`/more menu to show up.  I think you should file an issue on that documentation asking for clarity.